# What is the story of Sathya Sai meeting Swami Vivekananda in his next life?

Tags: vivekananda, sathya-sai

What is the story of Sathya Sai meeting Swami Vivekananda in his next life? When did Bhagavan Sathya Sai predict Vivekananda's rebirth? When did they meet for first time?

Comment: This is not mythology

Comment: Yes not history but something that is going to happen in the future @Pratimaputra

Comment: @Rickross are you sure of its happening in future?

Comment: I am not sure , I do not know :) @Pratimaputra

Answer (score 3):

SWAMI VIVEKANANDA: I have to come back once more. The Master said I am to come back once more with him.
MRS. ALLAN: You have to come back because Shri Ramakrishna says so?
SWAMI VIVEKANANDA: Souls like that have great power, Madam. 
http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/volume_9/conversations_and_interviews.htm

The story about the rebirth of Swami Vivekananda and his future involvment in the Sai Mission is well documented in the book "Sai Inner Views and Insight" by Howard Murphet, the well know and renowned worldwide author and devotee of Bhagavan Baba.

Here are some brief notes.

In the late 1960's Howard Murphet was in India with his wife Iris in one of the Sai ashram. In that occasion, Baba told Murphet and his wife: "Vivekananda has been reborn in Sri Lanka. When his education and training are complete, he will help me with my mission." The same announcement has been made by Swami to Andrew Schartz and to a few of his friends.

In March of 1987 a young man from Sri Lanka, whose name is Nalin Sedera, visited Prashanti Nilayam along with a group of people from his own country. An Australian devotee, Elvin Gates, was in the interview room with this group of Lankan people. Elvin Gates told that Sathya Sai Baba made the revelation to the young man the he was Vivekananda reborn. This took place on two successive days during two interviews in the private interview room. After the interview the news quickly spread throughout the ashram and crowds began to follow the young man.

Two years later, in 1989, Howard Murphet had the opportunity to talk to Nalin himself and had numerous information regarding the two interviews that he has had with Sai Baba.

Nalin said that before meeting Sathya Sai Baba he had a dream in which Swami, wearing a white dress, showed him an old couple, saying that they was his parents in a previous incarnation. When Nalid asked Swami to speak about his parents, Swami replied: "Forget about that. I am your father and your mother." In the interview room Swami asked him: "What is your name?" Nalin replied: "Nalin." Swami said: "Your are not Nalin, you are Naren." Narendra was the name of Swami Vivekananda and Naren was the name that Ramakrishna always used for his beloved disciple, Narendra.

Then Swami said: "In your previous birth you were a great saint. Do you know who Narendra was?" Nalin replied: "No, Swami, I don't." Sai Baba went on: "Narendra was the name of Vivekananda."

"I have been waiting for you for eighty-five years.", Swami said. Vivekananda left his body in 1902 and the interviw was in 1987, exactly eighty-five years later.

Swami said to Nalin that he will come to live in the Prashanti Nilayam ashram in the year 2021. That is the year in which Sathya Sai Baba has announced he will leave His body.(But he left his body earlier, since he is independent and who can stop him?)

Howard Murphet also says that Nalin has been back later to the ashram secretly and in incognito more than once.

More information and details in the book:

Ref: "Sai Inner Views and Insight", Chapter 10: "The Rebirth of Vivekananda" by Howard Murphet, Faber, VA, Leela Press, 1996, pp. 60-66

Comment: What is the credibility of all these? I think you are just belittling yourself and your idol by writing all these.After all, its not a preaching platform:)

Comment: And whats the objective of raising a question if you already know the answer except preaching?

Comment: All the lines you copied from the source site should be in the blockquote (yellow quote) .. Your own lines are to be in normal text (not yellow) .. are you able to make this blockquote?